# Handling a php double array with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to figure out how to do this -- I want to pass an array(array()) from PHP to jQuery. I've done it before with a single array but never with a nested array.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$sector_one   = array('one' => 0, 'two' => 1, 'three' => 0, 'four' => 0);
$sector_two   = array('one' => 0, 'two' => 1, 'three' => 0, 'four' => 0);
$sector_three = array('one' => 0, 'two' => 1, 'three' => 0, 'four' => 0); 
$sector_four  = array('one' => 0, 'two' => 1, 'three' => 0, 'four' => 0);

$array = [];
$array[0] = $sector_one;
$array[1] = $sector_two;
$array[2] = $sector_three;
$array[3] = $sector_four;
```

Now -- I haven't the slighest idea how to handle the data aspect of this once it's past to jquery. How would I go about accessing the information in $array[0]['one'] in jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply encode it using json_encode

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

And to get it back in jQuery

```
var array = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

// You can grab particular data like so:
console.log(array[0].one);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert this array to JSON and then return it to AJAX.  Something like this:

`return json_encode($array);`

Then in the front end you'll be able to treat the data as a JavaScript array.

It has been a while but I think something like the following should work in your AJAX (assuming the success variable is called `data`):

`var array = $.parseJSON(data);`